# someDataGridView.DataSource = someDataTable combines both tables, creates additional columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

all.

I'm currently working on a C# Winforms project.  I'm having a strange problem with making my DataGridViews stay properly formatted once I apply data to them.

Basically, what I've got is this...

```
DataGridView dgMainTable;
DataTable dtOtherTable;

...

/* Add and format columns for BOTH objects.  They're almost the same except for column widths */

...

/*Add data one row at a time to dtOtherTable*/

...

//Here's the kicker...
dgMainTable.DataSource = dtOtherTable;
```

Once I've done all of that, I expected to have dgMainTable filled with the data from dtOtherTable.  However, what I get is some strange collection of columns that is, as far as I can tell, both tables combined into one table.  So, in my case, I have six columns instead of the three I'm expecting.

Yes, I've been able to get around this problem by not formatting the first table.  If I comment out the code for that, the data gets assigned just as expected, but then I have no control over the first tables structure.  The structure shouldn't be defined by the table.  Given the structure of my code, that's just a bad place to do it.  How can I move the data from the other table to the main DataGridView while preserving the structure and formatting of the main table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **design** your `dgMainTable` yourself and you want to keep it, you have to **bind** data yourself with `AutoGenerateColumns` turned off (it's OK when on but not necessary in this case when all your columns are set-up manually). I suppose your `dgMainTable` has 3 columns `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3` and the corresponding columns in your `dtOtherTable` are `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` respectively. You have to add the following code (which manually bind data between the `dtOtherTable` and `dgMainTable`):

```
dgMainTable.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "Col1";
dgMainTable.Columns["Column2"].DataPropertyName = "Col2";
dgMainTable.Columns["Column3"].DataPropertyName = "Col3";
//bind data
dgMainTable.DataSource = dtOtherTable;
```